# Get number of changed features in a layer under edit mode using pyqgis

Tags: pyqgis, editing, feature-count

Is there a method I can find out, how many features in a layer have changed during edit mode (including changes in the attribute and the geometry)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to count the number of Features that are in the buffer (i.e that have changed since last commit on the layer) you can use the `editBuffer` of your `QgsVectorLayer`. It's a [`QgsVectorLayerEditBuffer`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayerEditBuffer.html) object which has interesting methods (`changedAttributeValues()`, `changedGeometries()`, `addedAttributes()`, `addedFeatures()`, ...)

```
# get a layer
layer = iface.activeLayer()

# get its editBuffer
buff = layer.editBuffer()

# make some changes in the layer...
  # changed geometries
buff.changedGeometries()
--> {61L: <qgis._core.QgsGeometry object at 0x7f8ed555e808>}

  # changed Attribute Value
buff.changedAttributeValues()

  # Number of changedFeatures regarding geometry or attributes
len(buff.changedGeometries()) + len(buff.changedAttributeValues())
```

Be aware that if you count the features that  have changed like that, you will count two times the same feature if you change it's geometry and one (or more) of it's attribute(s).

If you want the count of distinct features that have changed you can do something like that:

```
changed_geom =  buff.changedGeometries().keys() #list of feature ID
changed_attributes = buff.changedAttributeValues().keys() #list of feature ID
distinct_changed_features = set(changed_geom + changed_attributes) # set of distinct feature ID
number_changed_features = len(distinct_changed_features)
```

Now, if you want the count features that have change during an "Edit session" on a layer, you can connect to `editingStarted()` and `editingStopped` signals of `QgsVectorLayer` to implements a counter of modified features.

Comment: @Senwei Glad to help!