# Get number of changed features in a layer using pyqgis

Tags: pyqgis, editing, feature-count

I'm looking for a method to find out how many features in a layer have changed during edit mode (specifically attribute values). For my example i'm using QgsVectorLayerEditBuffer object, method ChangeAttributeValue().

I use editBuffer() method to get the layer buffer and after making some changes, I use ChangedAttributesValues(). This returns 'None'.
Example:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

buffer = layer.editBuffer()

..# make changes

buffer.changedAttributeValues()
..None
```

see also: [Get number of changed features in a layer under edit mode using pyqgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/305221/get-number-of-changed-features-in-a-layer-under-edit-mode-using-pyqgis/305305#305305)

Comment: Thx xunilk, this seems to work perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

Link refers number of changed features in a layer under edit mode so, if you commit changes, buffer (**QgsVectorLayerEditBuffer** object) will be lost. Complete procedure is as follows:

1) Load layer and in Python Console:

```
>>>layer = iface.activeLayer()
>>>buffer = layer.editBuffer()
>>>buffer #for corroborating object was produced
<qgis._core.QgsVectorLayerEditBuffer object at 0x7f81da97c948>
```

2) Click in "Toggle Editing button", open attributes table and make some changes in it; don't commit them. In my case, I only changed in my layer the first id feature. So, following command produces:

```
>>>buffer.changedAttributeValues()
{0: {0: 1}}
```

If a new change is produced, but I commit it, result is as follows:

```
>>>buffer.changedAttributeValues()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QgsVectorLayerEditBuffer has been deleted
```

For producing several consecutive changes, I change layer id three times in two records:

```
buffer = layer.editBuffer()
buffer.changedAttributeValues()
{0: {0: 3}, 1: {0: 2}}
```

However, only two changes were computed because layer has only two features.